# Get Method, Class and LineNumber from StatckTrace in Application_UnhandledException event

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, exception

I am developing Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Application. I want to do Application Level error handling instead of writing try...catch... in all methods. I need to extract Method Name, Class Name and Line Number where the actual error occurred. Below is the demo code. In Application_UnhandledException event, I am expecting **Method = "GenerateError" and Class = "ExceptionTesting"**. Also, I want to get LineNumber where the actual error occurred (this is not shown in code).

Code to generate Error:

```
public partial class ExceptionTesting : PhoneApplicationPage  
{
    // Generate Error to Test Exception Handling
    private void GenerateError()
    {
        Int16 i = Convert.ToInt16("test");
    }
}
```

Code that Handles Application Level Exception:

```
// Code to execute on Unhandled Exceptions
private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
StackTrace st = new StackTrace();

var query = st.GetFrames()         // get the frames
        .Select(frame => new
        {                   
            Method = frame.GetMethod(),
            Class = frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType
        });

foreach (var q in query)
{
    if (q.Method.Name.Contains("GenerateError"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Class: " + q.Class + ", Method: " + q.Method);
    }
}

if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
{
    // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
}
}
```

Comment: You've told us what you're trying to do but what is your question?

Comment: I am not getting Method = "GenerateError" and Class = "ExceptionTesting". It is showing System events (Load, Invoke etc). There isn't any class or method of my application in StackFrame arrary. All are from System Events only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application_UnhandledException` method is not called from your method where the exception happens, so `new StrackTrace()` will not be meaningful, as you have discovered.

To get the stack trace for the place where the exception occurred, use `e.Exception.StackTrace`.
Note that the real exception may be wrapped inside another exception, possibly several layers deep (`e.Exception.InnerException`).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/docs/windowsphone) to get this information.

Disclaimer: I am one of the cofounders